# Ng-Gauge directive in AngularJS, change Style of specific attribute of Ng-Gauge

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the angularJS ng-gauge directive.
Unfortunately, this directive does not allow you to change the fonts that
uses inside the Gauge. For example, the % remains in quantities smaller than the gauge number.

Below is an example on Html:

```
**<ng-gauge id = "active" size = "300" type = "full" thick = "25"
                  min = "0" max = "100" value = "active"
                  cap = "butt" label = "Active" append = "%"
                  foreground-color = "# 4ac682" background-color = "# EEE">
        </ ng-gauge>**
```

If I want to change **the style of the attribute "append"** that has the %, how should I do? I have looked everywhere
but despite being a very functional and useful directive, I have not found anything on how to do it.
Not even on official documentation.

Can you help me?